Adjoint with exponential map $e^{-A(t)} \left(\frac{d}{dt} \exp[B(t)] \right) e^{A(t)} =e^{-ad_A} \frac{d \exp[B(t)]}{dt}$
For a matrix, I know
\begin{align}
A e^{B} A^{-1} = e^{ABA^{-1}} = e^{Ad_A(B)}
\end{align}
Using the formula from Lie algebras, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \exp[B(t)] = \exp[B(t)] \frac{1-e^{-ad_B}}{ad_B} \frac{dB}{dt}
\end{align}
I want to find some nice formula
\begin{align}
e^{-A(t)} \left(\frac{d}{dt} \exp[B(t)] \right) e^{A(t)} \overset{?}{=} e^{-ad_A} \left(\frac{d}{dt} \exp[B(t)] \right)
\end{align}
Is my speculation correct? If so how one prove this formula?

If this is correct then how about
\begin{align}
e^{-A(t)}e^{-B(t)} \left(\frac{d}{dt} \exp[C(t)] \right) e^{B(t)}e^{A(t)} \overset{?}{=} e^{-ad_A} e^{-ad_B}\left(\frac{d}{dt} \exp[C(t)] \right)
\end{align}
and similar extension can be hold for general sequence of products?


Since $$B \cdot B' - B' \cdot B \ne 0$$ except for special commutative cases, the derivative of the Taylor sum of the exponential $e^{B}$ is not a simple multiple of the form $B'\cdot e^{B}$

I found answer from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula
Let
\begin{align}
f(s)Y := e^{sX} Y e^{-sX} 
\end{align}
One can solve $f(s)$ by taking differentiation of $\frac{d}{ds}$ and solve the differential equation. i.e.,
\begin{align}
\frac{d f(s)}{ds} Y = \frac{d}{ds}(e^{sX} Y e^{-sX}) = X e^{sX} Y e^{-sX} - e^{sX} Y e^{-sX} X = ad_X (e^{sX} Y e^{-sX}) 
\end{align}
so $f'(s) = ad_X f(s)$, with initial condition $f(0)=1$ we have $f(s)= e^{s ad_X}$. Replacing $X \mapsto -X$ we have desired result
